# React onClick not executing parent method

Tags: reactjs

Basically I have a connect 4 game and on a click on a column, I want the lowest unfilled circle in the column to fill and i want the app state to be updated.  The circle is being filled properly, so the ColumnClick() function works.  However, the next function called is to update the app state.  This should work so that when there is 4 in a row in the indicated column the board is not rendered, instead the message shows.  I have not implemented checking the whole board, because I want to first make sure clicking the column component is updating the app state.  This does not appeared  to be happening.  I have only shown the two relevant components here, the app and the column.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

TLDR: the play method should update the app state.  the details of one column should be passed to it after a column is clicked on and those should be copied to this.state of the app component

```
var redTurn = true;

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      column1: {id: 1, s6: "circle",s5:"circle",s4:"circle",s3:"circle",s2:"circle",s1:"circle"},
      column2: {id: 2, s6: "circle",s5:"circle",s4:"circle",s3:"circle",s2:"circle",s1:"circle"},
      column3: {id: 3, s6: "circle",s5:"circle",s4:"circle",s3:"circle",s2:"circle",s1:"circle"},
      column4: {id: 4, s6: "circle",s5:"circle",s4:"circle",s3:"circle",s2:"circle",s1:"circle"},
      column5: {id: 5, s6: "circle",s5:"circle",s4:"circle",s3:"circle",s2:"circle",s1:"circle"},
      column6: {id: 6, s6: "circle",s5:"circle",s4:"circle",s3:"circle",s2:"circle",s1:"circle"},
      column7: {id: 7, s6: "circle",s5:"circle",s4:"circle",s3:"circle",s2:"circle",s1:"circle"},
      gameOver: false
    };
    this.play = this.play.bind(this);
  }
  // some part of this si not working.  What? Why? Either the sate is not being updated or a method is not executing properly
  play(id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6){
    //find and select the column that matches the id 
    var column;
    for(column in this.state){
      if(column.id===id){
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return(
            column.s1= col1,
            column.s2= col2,
            column.s3= col3,
            column.s4= col4,
            column.s5= col5,
            column.s6= col6
          )
        });
      }
    }
    this.checkGameEnds();
  }
  checkGameEnds(){
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      if(this.state.s6!="circle" && this.state.column1.s6===this.state.column1.s5===this.state.column1.s4===this.state.column1.s3) return {gameOver: true};
    });
  }
  makeColumn(id, c, play){
    return <Column id={id} c={c} play={this.play}/>;
  }
  render(){
    if (!this.state.gameOver)return (
      <div className ="game">
        <Clock/>
        <div className="board">
          {this.makeColumn(this.state.column1.id, this.state.column1, this.play)}
          {this.makeColumn(this.state.column2.id, this.state.column2, this.play)}
          {this.makeColumn(this.state.column3.id, this.state.column3, this.play)}
          {this.makeColumn(this.state.column4.id, this.state.column4, this.play)}
          {this.makeColumn(this.state.column5.id, this.state.column5, this.play)}
          {this.makeColumn(this.state.column6.id, this.state.column6, this.play)}
          {this.makeColumn(this.state.column7.id, this.state.column7, this.play)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    else return <h1>Oh shiiiittttt</h1>
  }
}


class Column extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.id,
      c1: 1,
      c2: 2,
      c3: 3,
      c4: 4,
      c5: 5,
      c6: 6,
      col1: this.props.c.s1,
      col2: this.props.c.s2,
      col3: this.props.c.s3,
      col4: this.props.c.s4,
      col5: this.props.c.s5,
      col6: this.props.c.s6
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.columnClick();
    this.props.play(this.state.id, this.state.col1, this.state.col2, this.state.col3, this.state.col4, this.state.col5, this.state.col6);
  }

  columnClick(){
    redTurn = !redTurn;
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      if(redTurn){
        if(this.state.col6 === "circle")return {col6: "circleRed"};
        else if(this.state.col5 === "circle")return {col5: "circleRed"};
        else if(this.state.col4 === "circle")return {col4: "circleRed"};
        else if(this.state.col3 === "circle")return {col3: "circleRed"};
        else if(this.state.col2 === "circle")return {col2: "circleRed"};
        else if(this.state.col1 === "circle")return {col1: "circleRed"};
      }
      else{
        if(this.state.col6 === "circle")return {col6: "circleBlack"};
        else if(this.state.col5 === "circle")return {col5: "circleBlack"};
        else if(this.state.col4 === "circle")return {col4: "circleBlack"};
        else if(this.state.col3 === "circle")return {col3: "circleBlack"};
        else if(this.state.col2 === "circle")return {col2: "circleBlack"};
        else if(this.state.col1 === "circle")return {col1: "circleBlack"};
      }
    });
  }
  makeCell(id, col){
    return <Square id={id} col={col}/>;
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="column" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <div>{this.makeCell(this.state.c1, this.state.col1)}</div> 
        <div>{this.makeCell(this.state.c2, this.state.col2)}</div> 
        <div>{this.makeCell(this.state.c3, this.state.col3)}</div> 
        <div>{this.makeCell(this.state.c4, this.state.col4)}</div> 
        <div>{this.makeCell(this.state.c5, this.state.col5)}</div> 
        <div>{this.makeCell(this.state.c6, this.state.col6)}</div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `Column` component  do a `console.log(this.props)` and let us know what your getting as props.

Comment: {id: 1, c: {…}, play: ƒ}
c: {id: 2, s6: "circle", s5: "circle", s4: "circle", s3: "circle", …}
id: 1
play: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object.    @BARNOWL

Comment: now `console.log(this.props.play)` and show what you are getting.  not able to see the rest

Comment: {id: 7, c: {…}, play: ƒ}
c: {id: 7, s6: "circle", s5: "circle", s4: "circle", s3: "circle", …}
id: 7
play: ƒ ()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 7
name: "bound play"
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[TargetFunction]]: play(id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) { //find and select the column that matches the id var column; for (column in this.state) { if (column.id === id) { this.setState((state, props) => {…}
[[BoundThis]]: App
[[BoundArgs]]: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: ok do you think you can make a codesandbox of this please ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sunset-73mgk?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

In `play` method you're not returning the updated state object, Put {}, as I pointed in the following code in the comment, `//you need to return the state object, put {}`

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
          return( // you need to return the state object, put {}
            column.s1= col1,
            column.s2= col2,
            column.s3= col3,
            column.s4= col4,
            column.s5= col5,
            column.s6= col6
          )
        });
```

You wrongly used the updater function.

> The output of the updater is shallowly merged with state, [DOC](http://The%20output%20of%20the%20updater%20is%20shallowly%20merged%20with%20state)

But you're not returning the object that would be merged to produce the expected updated state.

So change to:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
            column.s1= col1,
            column.s2= col2,
            column.s3= col3,
            column.s4= col4,
            column.s5= col5,
            column.s6= col6
          }
        });
```

---

Update:
Moreover, your object formation is also problematic:

You need something like that:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
            column1: Object.assign(prevState.column1, {s1: col1}),
            column2: Object.assign(prevState.column2, {s2: col2}) ,
            column3: Object.assign(prevState.column3, {s3: col3}) ,
            column4: Object.assign(prevState.column4, {s4: col4}) ,
            column5: Object.assign(prevState.column5, {s5: col5}) ,
            column6: Object.assign(prevState.column6, {s6: col6}) ,
          }
        });
```

I showed above for one column, please change for others accordingly.

If you don't know how `Object.assign` merges objects, read [this MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: I think the OP has already done this in the code above...

Comment: "Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with state." https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Where exactly is the OP going to apply this solution on ?

Comment: In `play` method.

Comment: hmmmm... i do not see a difference between your code, and the code that is in play method already. It looks identical.

Comment: see the comment ` // you need to return the state object, put {}`

Comment: I did a side by side comparison, and your code is no different than the OP's code. Butt... its up to OP to judge.

Comment: I am also confused as to what I should add

Comment: thank you for adding that - I inserted your code and now when I run the project, I get Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," and the period between column and s1 is pointed to.  Note sure why

Comment: This is because of the missing property key

Comment: Why you're modifying the state? you need return the complete updated state copy object.

Comment: I edited the answer showing how you should format the updated object.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me toward that Object.assign method.  I would like to only update the column that is clicked on, not every column in the app as only the one needs to be updated.  Is that an option with Object.assign?  Also, the col1-col6 parameters are for circles in a column, not columns themselves (they should be renamed).  The idea of the for loop and if statement before the state update is to only update the column that was clicked on

Comment: Did this solved the issue ? im looking into the sandbox.

Comment: I am confident that play method is the issue, what I need to figure out is how to update only the column that is clicked on in a call to setState.  As far as I can tell I am unable to do this with Object.assign @BARNOWL

Comment: So im looking into this on code sandbox and... the play method is getting called from the parent method. im not sure on what the issue is you're having exactly.

I restructured the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-voice-62rt7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you're still having issues, i would advice you to make a new question that is more specific.

Comment: the issue is that the play method should update the app state, so that when winning conditions are met the game can end.  right now clicking on a column drops a peice, but does not update the board state.  this makes it impossible to test for four in a row

Comment: btw,I tried give with general strategy to solve the issues I noticed in your code.